# Magento export error 500

Tags: php, magento, export

When I try to export about 1200 product with the Export > Data Profile > Export all tool, it throws an error 500.

When I do the same thing with just one group of products, it works out fine.

My Server Setup:

```
log_errors  On  
max_execution_time  36000
max_input_time  300
max_input_vars  10000
memory_limit    1024M
```

It says I should look in the error log, but there are no errors showing. 
I am running out oof things to test here. Could it be some broken product?

Comment: 500 is an Internal Server Error.  I don't know magento but maybe there is a limit of bytes you can send from the server or there is a limit of bytes your can get from the DB.

Comment: What are these limits names?

Comment: @ScubaBen 

1200 aren't that many products. I usually have problems when it's over 5000 products. It may be a product issue then.

What I do in these cases is to separate products and do different exports: one for configurable, one for simple etc.

If you don't have different types of products, just do it by price range, small slots like 20 products and then increase it. Maybe you will be able to spot the buggy products.

Comment: @Claudiu what you say is, what I suspect. Is there a way to check product tables integrity?

Comment: It's likely that the server is timing out despite your settings.  Does it run for a consistent time before throwing the 500 error?  Which logs are you looking at? Are you looking at Magento's error logs? (possibly worth a look) or I would guess /var/log/httpd/error_log?

Answer (score -1):

app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Entity/Product.php

line: 873

$dataRow += $stockItemRows[$productId];

In order to update the code to:

$dataRow = array_merge($dataRow,$stockItemRows[$productId]);